# Access 2007 response time

Tags: ms-access

This database is linked to SQL tables. I used multiple queries to open duplicate forms because the different criteria.  Then I tried creating the search criteria with macros in the where condition.  Both ways are extremely slow.

Should this be handled through the "on Load" Even Procedure? With an If statement? to get the results of each query currently used.

Comment: Show us the code, SQL, trace output, anything!  There's not enough information for anyone to provide a meaningful response.  What does the data look like?  How many records?  Have you traced the calls to the SQL Server?  How do they perform outside Access?

Comment: calm down, read you question slowly, and...rewrite it clearly :-)

Comment: I have no idea what this question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

From your question the key part that stood out as a potential problem area was the part about using macros in the WHERE clause. The problem with that is you will have to bring lots of records down the wire to your local computer to do the processing.

Its like ringing a car dealer and saying “I would like to by a red car and it has to fit in my garage” The dealer knows what red cars he has (index) but does not know anything about your garage so has to drive each car (record) to your house (computer) and try to fit it in your garage!

If you can move all the processing to the server it would help , so expanding on the car example you ring up and say “I want a red car that is no wider than 4’” The dealer can now just send the cars (records) that match that criteria to your house (computer).

That’s all the help I can be for now until more information is provided

Comment: My appoligies for being so vague, but Kevin's reply is what I needed to hear, it will help me restructure what is already built. Which is what I was looking for. Kenin, I completly understand using SQL as the work horse, but you can't run queries then read them in Access "that I know of".. Is there a way to read "Views" form SQL into Access 2007?  Or what other alternative to have SQL do the queries that are normally performed in Access when not linked to SQL db.

Comment: Criteria passed via a macro are not going to be processed on the local machine if Jet/ACE can hand it off to the server, so I think the concern here is completely overblown.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton The way I read the question (which is rather vague to be fair) was that he had user/access functions in the where clause. If however it was just simple criteria being made up by the macro then you are of course right and the server would do the processing.

Comment: @user745778 You can have a view as a linked table in the same way that you would link a normal table